# Check if this system has any attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, stability-theory, biology

We have the following system:
\begin{cases} 
      h'=h(1-h-a_{12}p) & \\
      p'=\rho p(1-p-a_{21}h) &, \rho>0, a_{12}>1, a_{21}\in (0,1).\\ 
   \end{cases}
We want to see if we have an attractor.
So far I have managed to determine the stationary points:
$(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (h^*,p^*) $, where $h^*$ and $p^*$ are solutions of the system \begin{cases} 
      1-h-a_{12}p=0 & \\
      1-p-a_{21}h=0&, \rho>0, a_{12}>1, a_{21}\in (0,1).\\ 
   \end{cases}
I investigated the stability of the stationary points and found the following:$(0,0)$ is unstable, $(1,0)$ is stable ( asymptotically) and $(0,1)$ is stable( asymptotically).I can't figure out how to determine the stability of the fourth point $(h^*,p^*).$ Next I would like to see if we have attractors, for this I was thinking to determine the null-clines. Please give me a little help in determining these null-clines and and a hint about the attractor.

Comment: The nullclines are just unions of straight lines. And it might be useful to play around with the [phase portrait](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bx%281-x-4y%2F3%29%2Cy%281-y-x%2F2%29%7D%2C+x%3D-1..3%2C+y%3D-1..3) a little; then you will notice that your conclusion about $(1,0)$ doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: By the way, I don't know the context where you encountered this, but it's a model for two competing species and is explained in many mathematical biology textbooks (such as Edelstein-Keshet).

Comment: And you can find lecture notes etc. if you search the web for “competing species model” or something similar.